# When restarting ligttpd, how do I get fastcgi php-cgi's to restart

Tags: php, lighttpd, fastcgi

I'm running lighttpd with php5-cgi. Running `/etc/init.d/lighttpd restart` does not cause the php-cgi processes to restart. Should I just `killall` them, or is there a more appropriate way to get them to restart?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you try one of these init scripts:

http://blog.codefront.net/2007/06/11/nginx-php-and-a-php-fastcgi-daemon-init-script/
or
http://tomasz.sterna.tv/2009/04/php-fastcgi-with-nginx-on-ubuntu/

didnt try them myself but i guess i have to in the next days but it seems appropiate to reload php-fastcgi via (example code):

```
/etc/init.d php-cgi stop
/etc/init.d php-cgi start
```

maybe you can share your experience

or try to:
"Change your PHP binary to FPM instead of old fastcgi"
as suggested in another answer here.
that solved it for me!